# Email Service - Reply to

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

We have an Email Service, which works sending email to the long email service like below :

[image]

If we send the email from a standard Object - say - Lead :

How can we put the long email serivce into the set Reply to? (BTW - If we put the email service to CC - we will never get the service to work if he user didnt push the "Reply All")...

How can we solve it?

Only development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically what you would do is:

1. Define a general –or specific– purpose email address on your email server, e.g.: info@yourcompany.com or support@yourcompany.com and setup an automatic forward to your email service long address.
2. You then register your friendly email address as a org-wide default email address in Salesforce setup.

Note: You will be contacting your leads, etc from the org-wide default email address (vs current user email address), when you want the replies to be processed by your email service.

Voila!

Comment: Many Thanks!!

The context user inside the email service will get the approval of the org-wide email address? 

Can you please just detail a little more section 1? Means, how to define a shorter
name and forward this automatically?

Comment: You do that on your email server (not Salesforce) just create an address like sales@yourdomain.com or support@yourdomain.com and set the automatic forward to the long address. “Where to do that” depends on your email server.

Comment: Thanks!
I did it in Gmail - but when I copy the email service (long email like in the pic attached in the question ) to the forward emails -   It still wants a verification from the Email... I don't know where it sends the verification email

Comment: This post (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70821/salesforce-email-service-debugging) explains how you can debug inbound emails to your email service and get the confirmation link gmail sent. You will have to re-send the confirmation email from gmail after turning on the debuglog or requesting Email Snapshot feature activation.

Comment: Thanks a lot...